# How to call in Custom Post-Type Categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have our portfolio page here: http://www.slarc.com/portfolio-view/central-control-building-east-texas/

The orange links below the project title are manually inserted on the page content. Is there a way to call in a the post categories to make this automatic?

The template I'm using doesn't have our portfolio posts under WP Posts. It's under a custom post-type titled "Portfolio".

I have received this code below.  But I don't know how to add it to my page.  When I tried everything on the page below the PHP code disappeared.

```
<?php  
$args = array( 
    'type'                     => 'post', 
    'child_of'                 => 0, 
    'parent'                   => '', 
    'orderby'                  => 'name', 
    'order'                    => 'ASC', 
    'hide_empty'               => 1, 
    'hierarchical'             => 1, 
    'exclude'                  => '', 
    'include'                  => '', 
    'number'                   => '', 
    'taxonomy'                 => 'your_custom_taxonomy', 
    'pad_counts'               => false ); 
$categories = get_categories($args); 

echo '<ul>'; 

foreach ($categories as $category) { 
    $url = get_term_link($category);?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li> 
<?php 
} 

echo '</ul>'; 
?>
```

Thanks,
Lorne

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure without knowing what Taxonomy the "Portfolio" post type is using. Even though it's a different post type, it might still be using the default category taxonomy. If it is, then you don't need to use `get_categories();` as you're doing above. The following should work:

```
<?php get_the_category_list('|'); ?>
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because `'your_custom_taxonomy'` isn't a valid taxonomy. You can always [turn on debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in WordPress to show you any errors that are popping up, instead of just seeing a blank page.

For more info, see [get_the_category_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list) and [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

If you're trying to display only the terms that are applied to a given post (not all of the categories available), for a taxonomy `portfolio_category`, try the following:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category' ); ?>
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However that didn't work?  I need to turn on debugging and try to get to the bottom of this.  I think it's a custom post type and not a custom taxonomy.  But I didn't make this template, where do I find that out?

Comment: It might be a custom post type _using_ a custom taxonomy. This is a little more complex than I can explain here. You might want to read http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types, and http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies.
Generally you can figure out the taxonomy by going to wherever you set up the post categories in the backend and looking at the URL. If it's a custom taxonomy the URL will end with something like `edit-tags.php?taxonomy=custom_cat&post_type=custom_type`

Comment: Ok so I got it to pull in the post categories.  Turns out it was a custom taxonomy named: portfolio_category.  I used teh code above and changed the taxonomy name.

However it pulls in ALL my categories, even if they are unchecked in the edit post page?  I have tried hide_empty to both 1 and 0.  Neither made an impact.

Comment: I didn't realize you were trying to list the applied terms, and not all terms. See my edit above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...the get_the_term_list worked great.  However as with everything else I do in web design I want to through a curveball in the mix.

I am getting the links working on this page for "portfolio_category" here: http://www.slarc.com/portfolio-view/central-control-building-east-texas/

However if you look at the link for Administration Buildings it returns this link for the category: http://www.slarc.com/portfolio_category/administration-buildings/

I have a specific page I want to direct it to: http://www.slarc.com/projects/administration-buildings/

How can I do this?

Comment: This is the code I got to work, now I just want the start of the link to be: http://www.slarc.com/projects/.

    <?php
                echo '<h3 id="Proj_Categories"><ul>';
                    echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category', '<li>', '</li><li>', '</li>' );
                echo '</ul></h3>';
            ?>

Comment: FYI, the slugs on my portfolio pages, all match the portfolio_category slugs exactly. So If I can echo that portfolio_category at the end of the "http: //www. slarc.com/projects /"